# Order of layers on profile page

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

Here is a small snippet from a screenshot of my profile page showing my avatar with a hat and surrounding graphical elements:

[image: example of avatar with hat and surrounding graphical elements]

As you see, the order of the layers is not consistent. Either the hat should be on top of everything else (including the dots from the badges) or the order should be avatar picture, the hat, and everything else on top of that.

It's certainly not a huge problem (I hesitate to call it "bug"), but nevertheless it's bothering me, because, yes, I can be that pedantic.

Comment: Well i too noticed and what i found from my little exp is that they have to remove position:relative from icon(.badge1) and this issue will be done.. :) hope i did not made any issue by my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now: [z-index on badge icon is incorrect with hats overlapping it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271326/z-index-on-badge-icon-is-incorrect-with-hats-overlapping-it/271554#271554)